# Viscoplastic Anand Model of Solder Alloy

Tags: classical-mechanics, solid-state-physics, material-science, models, solid-mechanics

I have found some data of viscoplastic Anand model for the SAC305 solder joint of electronic devices in the literature. Does this data depend on the thickness, length and width of the joint? I mean that can I use this model data for any SAC305 solder material?

Thanks a lot,
Mohsen

Comment: One might think that the articles where you found the data might indicate the range of applicability?

Comment: @JonCuster They hadn't told anything about the applicability!

Answer (score 0):

The SAC305 viscoplastic response is highly dependent on its microstructure. Depending on the specimen dimensions and the process, the microstructure may vary a lot. I advise you to consider an Anand model that has been determined from representative test specimen with a representative loading. For instance, a lot of papers deal with Anand model determination from monotonic tensile tests performed on dog-bone samples, however, real solder joints are way smaller than dog-bone samples and are mainly subjected to cyclic shear sollicitations.

Resaerchers from the Auburn university have done a lot of good work regarding the determination of SAC305 Anand parameters. Lately, Libot et al. have presented a paper at SMTAi 2022 which presents a set of Anand parameters determined from actual solder joints (the test vehicle is a reflowed electronic assembly) subjected to thermal cycling, which ensure a pretty good representativity (Thermomechanical Durability Model of 96.5Sn-3.0Ag-0.5Cu (SAC305) Solder Interconnects in Wafer Level Packaging (WLP))

Best regards

JB

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).